# Flatlist: A VirtualizedList contains a cell which itself contains more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the parent list

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist, flatlist

I am getting the following error in my implementation of FlatList

> 

```
A VirtualizedList contains a cell with more than one VirtualizedList of the same orientation as the parent list. You must pass a unique listKey prop to each sibling list.

VirtualizedList trace:
  Child (vertical):
    listKey: rootList-header
    cellKey: rootList-header
  Parent (vertical):
    listKey: function listKey(item, index) {
          return 'createEX' + index.toString();
        }
    cellKey: rootList
```

I am also adding relevant code. The code works when I test using expo, although the error comes up. The app crashes in TestFlight.

This is my FlatList Implementation. If I remove the MetNeedsMenu part, the code works.

```
       <FlatList style={stylesCreate.scrollStyle}
            listKey={(item, index) => {return 'createEX' + index.toString()}}
            ListHeaderComponent={
                <View style={stylesCreate.createForm}>
                <Text style={styles.screenTitle}>CREATE NEW{"\n"}ENTRY</Text>
                <Text style={stylesCreate.label}>How are you feeling now?</Text>
                <Dropdown mood={newMoodBefore} setMood={setMoodBefore}/>
                <Text style={stylesCreate.label}>Select the areas of life that made you feel grateful.</Text>
                <MetNeedsMenu selectedNeeds={needs} setSelectedNeeds={setNeeds}/>
                <InfoButton/>
                <Text style={stylesCreate.label}>What are you grateful for?</Text>
                <GratitudeInput value={newEntry} placeholder="Write Here..." setValue={setEntry}/>
                <Text style={stylesCreate.label}>How are you feeling after doing the activity?</Text>
                <Dropdown mood={newMoodAfter} setMood={setMoodAfter}/>
                <CustomButton text='CREATE' onPress={addEntry}></CustomButton>
                </View>
            }
            >
       </FlatList>
```

This is my MetNeedsMenu implementation.

```
const K_OPTIONS = [
  {
    item: 'Physical Wellbeing:',
    id: '1',
  },
  {
    item: 'Peace & Calm',
    id: '2',
  },
  {
    item: 'Energizing Moments',
    id: '3',
  },
  {
    item: 'Engagement / Flow',
    id: '4',
  },
  {
    item: 'Connection',
    id: '5',
  },
  {
    item: 'Accomplishment',
    id: '6',
  },
  {
    item: 'Meaning / Fulfillment',
    id: '7',
  },
  {
    item: 'Others',
    id: '8',
  }
]

const MetNeedsMenu = ({ selectedNeeds, setSelectedNeeds }) => {

  return (
    <View style={{ marginBottom: 20}}>
      <SelectBox
        width={300}
        label="Select multiple"
        options={K_OPTIONS}
        selectedValues={selectedNeeds}
        onMultiSelect={onMultiChange()}
        onTapClose={onMultiChange()}
        hideInputFilter={true}
        isMulti
        listKey={(item, index) => {return index.toString()}}
        labelStyle={{
            fontSize: 15,
            color: '#0060ff',
        }}
        containerStyle={{
            backgroundColor: '#ffffff',
            borderRadius: 5,
        }}
        arrowIconColor={'blue'} //style for dropdown arrow
        optionsLabelStyle={{ //style for labels of options
            color: 'black',
            paddingLeft: 10,
            fontSize: 15,
        }}
        multiOptionContainerStyle={{ //style multiple selections
            backgroundColor: '#0060ff',
        }}
        multiListEmptyLabelStyle={{ //style for SELECT text
            paddingLeft: 10,
        }}
        toggleIconColor={'#0060ff'} //style color of select icon
        selectedItemStyle={{
          paddingLeft: 10,
        }}
      />

    </View>
  )

  function onMultiChange() {
    return (item) => setSelectedNeeds(xorBy(selectedNeeds, [item], 'id'))
  }

}
```

I am guessing the problem lies with MultiNeedsMenu, but I have put listKey there with no success

Answer (score 0):

The error tells you that you have a **FlatList** or **Scrollview** inside another **FlatList** or **Scrollview** with the same orientation. What is possible to do is to have nested FlatList or ScrollView of different orientation. Here is an example:

```
<FlatList 
  data={...}
  keyExtracto={...}>

 <ScrollView horizontal>
  <Text>One</Text>
  <Text>Two</Text>
 </ScrollView>

</FlatList>
```